# having problem lauching "variety" wallpaper changer

Tags: 16.04, desktop-background

i have a software named "variety" installed on my ubuntu 16.04 version.
in the preference section of this software i have selected to enable it with the system startup.

now the problem is sometimes it doesn't get launched at startup and those times it doesn't start at all no matter what i do.

so is there any solution to solve this problem.

Comment: i am sorry to say but can you please be more specific.i mean i am actually new in ubuntu so i don't even know how to edit startup command.

Comment: You have solved the problem yourself by typing `variety slideshow` so I'm deleting inquiring comments and answer which was unsuccessful.